# Android media recorder crashes on stop

Tags: android, google-api, android-mediarecorder, android-camera2

I'm trying to implement camera2api provided by google with this link
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video

Everything works fine but after after stoping the video the app crashes on mediarecorder.stop()

I'm using Xiaomi 4A

Logcat:

4-21 23:37:42.189 20375-20375/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.android.camera2video, PID: 20375
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
                                                       at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
                                                       at com.example.android.camera2video.Camera2VideoFragment.stopRecordingVideo(Camera2VideoFragment.java:687)
                                                       at com.example.android.camera2video.Camera2VideoFragment.onClick(Camera2VideoFragment.java:314)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)

Comment: post the logcat of the crash

Comment: I have updated the question. Kindly check

Comment: Same issue :( Got any progress?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the same link and it was crashing on mediarecorder.onStop() on my **Xiaomi 4A** and it was giving IllegalStateException but code was working perfectly fine with other devices.

I solved the issue by simply updating my device using miui updater.